# YouTube API V3 Update Videos with recordingDetails

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Are you able to add or update the `recordingDetails` on a video that has been uploaded to YouTube already?

Using the follow snippet of code, I am able to change the titles and descriptions. I would like to be able to add the locationDescription, latitude and longitude. Except they seem to be ignored with no errors when passing them.

```
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$listResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos("snippet,recordingDetails", array('id' => $videoId));
$video = $listResponse[0];
$videoSnippet = $video['snippet'];
$recordingDetails = $video['recordingDetails'];
$videoSnippet['description'] = $videoDesc;
$recordingDetails['locationDescription'] = $address;
$recordingDetails['location']['latitude'] = $latitude;
$recordingDetails['location']['longitude'] = $longitude;
$updateResponse = $youtube->videos->update("snippet,recordingDetails", $video);
```

When adding new videos I have the option to add those values just not add them later.

Comment: You may want to first see this [update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#april-28-2016) with recordingDetails and this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails.location) for possible values. With this, check and make sure that you have specified values correctly. 
Also, [Videos: update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update) might help.

Comment: YoutubeAPI deprecated a location properties https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#recordingDetails.location